# Least squares with matrix product constraints

Tags: oc.optimization-and-control

I am encountering a constrained LS problem with the following structure:
$$
\text{min}_Q\ \sum_{i=1}^M ||Q_i X_i-Y_i||_F^2
$$
$$
\text{s.t. }\ Q_M Q_{M-1}\cdots Q_1=I,
$$
where $Q_i,X_i,Y_i\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ are full rank.

I understand this can be a very hard problem. I just want to know if there is a numerically converging algorithm for this type of problem by any chance.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni Sorry, it should be a sum of squared norms, but $Q$ is not orthogonal.